# How to add "Open terminal here" to Nautilus' context menu?

Tags: nautilus, software-installation

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

I want to add "Open terminal here" to Nautilus context or right-click menu but it tries to download 32bit version from Internet.

Comment: I really don't understand the question. Could you reformulate and explain it differently?

Comment: @Hanynowsky its a feature found in Xubuntu/xfce.

Comment: It's actually a feature that plugs into nautilus, so ordinary Ubuntu works, as well as many others that use nautilus.

Comment: the feature is also found in cinnamon

Comment: The solution in some of the answers is to install a package. There is no longer a need to install a package because this feature seems to be already present in 16.04.

Comment: ubuntu 18.10, right click in the background of nautilus

Answer (score 357, accepted):

You have to install the [nautilus-open-terminal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nautilus-open-terminal) package from the universe repositories for Ubuntu versions up to Ubuntu 15.04:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

If you want to install it with apturl, use this URL: apt://nautilus-open-terminal

Then:

```
nautilus -q
```

In order to restart Nautilus

[image: Result]

In Ubuntu 15.10, the functionality is [already included](https://askubuntu.com/q/692567/2355) in `nautilus`!

Comment: I notice that in 13.04 raring ringtail it has disappeared from the "Files" menu and is now only available in the right-click menu. :-(

Comment: Any idea on how to make it use the normal terminal settings? The terminal it opened didn't have the normal colors and settings.

Comment: @snapfractalpop Do you verify that the terminal it opens is the one you expected? There is not one terminal program only on an Ubuntu install (at least `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`).

Comment: @air-dex It seems to open xterm with the command ```/usr/bin/xterm -e /bin/sh -c cd '/whatever/folder' && exec $SHELL``` basically changing directories upon startup of the terminal session. I don't know how to modify this behavior to use xfce4-terminal (which is what I've been using).

Comment: @Jobin Nope. The package is still available for 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr": http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nautilus-open-terminal

Comment: Works for 14.04 too.

Comment: Of course, the one thing I actually want to use this for, opening a samba share in the terminal, doesn't work here. The "open in terminal" is missing.   Feels like Louie CK trying to fix his daughter's doll

Comment: I'm in 16.04, and while the menu entry is present, it is about as utterly broken and badly-designed as it could possibly be. Firstly, it's only on a context menu, so there is no keyboard shortcut, not even alt-navigating the pulldowns. Secondly, when I select it, it opens gnome-terminal in my $HOME, not in the selected directory.

Comment: In 16.04 there is no `nautilus-open-terminal` package. Use `nautilus-actions` instead.

Comment: Any Ideas on how make it works in `18.04` ? Because none works

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1206655/113640 for 2020 answer.

Answer (score 43):

`nautilus-open-terminal` and `nautilus-actions` packages are available in Universe repository of Ubuntu 14.04. So run the below commands to enable universe repository and also to install  above mentioned  packages.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Finally run `nautilus -q` command to quit nautilus.Now you can be able to see `Open in terminal` option on right-clicking.

Comment: Hadn't had a chance to try it on 14.04 yet.  But I just did and it worked. :)  Thanks again!

Comment: Is the universe repository enabled per default? I did not have add it manually.

Comment: it isn't enabled by default. You have to add it manually.

Comment: +1 for "sudo add-apt-repository universe" which I was looking for :)

Comment: For Ubuntu 20 just install `nautilus-actions`.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my script to open terminal in the current directory,

I built my own after the open-terminal plugin stopped working for me

```
#!/bin/bash
##################################
# A nautilus script to open gnome-terminal in the current directory
# place in ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts
##################################
#                                       Remove file:// from CURRENT_URI
gnome-terminal --working-directory=`echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI" | cut -c 8-`
```

PS: Here is some bonus info

Assigning a shortcut to the script

- Add executable script to ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts
- Wait some time - nautilus regenerates accels file
- Edit file ~/.gnome2/accels/nautilus
- Find line similar to this one:

`; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ScriptsGroup/script_file:\\s\\s\\shome\\sgautam\\s.gnome2\\snautilus-scripts\\sopen-terminal" "")`

- Remove comment (semicolon) and specify shortcut like this:

`(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ScriptsGroup/script_file:\\s\\s\\shome\\sgautam\\s.gnome2\\snautilus-scripts\\sopen-terminal" "<Primary><Shift>t")`

- Save file.
- Logout - login.

Comment: Will it work on nautilus-GTK3 ?

Comment: Not sure, I am using it on plain ubuntu 12.04 x64, give it a shot .

Comment: In 14.04, Gnome 13.12, the script works, but the shortcut assignment method does not.

Answer (score 8):

Just use:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
```

and Logout/Login or reboot.

Comment: Thanks! Do not need to reboot or logout, just run `nautilus -q` in terminal will be OK.

Answer (score 5):

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop edition today 07-18-2014, and all I had to do to get the command line option in Nautilus was the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
nautilus -q
```

Comment: sorry ,how it is different from accepted answer?

Comment: IIRC a lot of different solutions were posted, some speaking of different ubuntu versions requiring different methods -- so I posted my experience on my version at the time.

Comment: I appreciate you-don't mind-this post came on review,that is the only reason I posted the comment

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to install `nautilus-admin` (make sure to install the additional files) to have the right click option and others as well, since `nautilus-open-terminal` is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Ubuntu `18.04` or newer:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
```

Comment: This is not an addon to open a terminal in the current directory, but to open a nautilus window with root permissions or edit a file with root permissions. The accepted answer is still valid for 18.04. You may want to delete your answer.

Comment: @vanadium The accepted answer does not work for me. This one does as it also add 'open in terminal' when right clicking on folder.

Comment: It might work for you as a workaround, but does not provide a correct answer on the question how to add an open in terminal right-click item. What this answer does is open a dangerous terminal with root permissions. Therefore, I do not consider this a good answer for general use.

Comment: Actually, the right-click menu action now is provided by the package nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal, which in Ubuntu is installed by default

Answer (score 1):

I used @Gautam's solution until I found it will not work (I mean a script itself) if path contains non-ascii characters because it's URL encoded.

Here is my little fix which is working at least for me.
So, the script should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

According to `gnome-terminal` docs, when you execute this:

```
cd path/to/dir
gnome-terminal
```

`gnome-terminal` will use `path/to/dir` as working directory, which explains why that script works.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and try again.

Or

```
cd /tmp  
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nautilus-open-terminal/nautilus-open-terminal_0.20-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i nautilus*deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the **.bashrc** file in Home.
2. Open it with any text editor.
3. Add a line at the end: `cd $PWD`
4. Save it.
5. Close all instances of Nautilus
6. Now, when you open Nautilus you will get to see the "Open in terminal" option in the right-click menu and it loads the current directory path when clicked.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For recent versions of Ubuntu (eg. 18)... create/save this script in:

`~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`

*Note: you need to also chg the permission of this new file to allow execution*

It will add a Scripts right click context menu item (with the name given e.g. 'open-in-terminal.sh') for any file or directory you click in nautilus.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# When a directory is selected, go there. Otherwise go to current
# directory. If more than one directory is selected, show error.
if [ -n "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" ]; then
    set $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        destination="$1"
        # Go to file's directory if it's a file
        if [ ! -d "$destination" ]; then
            destination="`dirname "$destination"`"
        fi
    else
        zenity --error --title="ERROR! Open terminal here" \
            --text="Plz only select one directory."
        exit 1
    fi
else
    destination="`echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI" | sed 's/^file:\/\///'`"
fi

# It's only possible to go to local directories
if [ -n "`echo "$destination" | grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9]\+:'`" ]; then
    zenity --error --title="ERROR! Open terminal here" \
        --text="Sorry, only local directories can be used."
    exit 1
fi

gnome-terminal --working-directory="$destination"
```

*Based on this source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto/SampleScripts#Open_terminal_here*

Answer (score -2):

This link provides the best working solution for adding the feature "Open terminal here" as context command menu for a folder.

http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/add-open-terminal-here-to-file-menu-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Link only answers are frowned on here. Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Put essential parts of link into your answer , not just link