# How can I 'cd' into directory from folder in desktop gui view?

Tags: directory, navigation, cd-command

Is there a way to open up a terminal from a folder location in a desktop folder?

This functionality would be the same as 'cdto' in OS X:
https://github.com/jbtule/cdto/releases/tag/2_6_0

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu

Comment: Please post as comment so that I can mark your answer as correct!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the related question, you can install the Nautilus plugin like this:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

[How to add "Open terminal here" to Nautilus' context menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu)

Comment: Some people might prefer `nautilus-terminal` which lets one open a terminal embedded in the nautilus view. I prefer the "open terminal here" as per your answer, but the difference between the two is more UI style than functionality.