# How to save current directory path from terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is there any way to save the path of the current directory from the current Gnome Terminal window?

I need this when I open another terminal and have to type `cd` repeatedly again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in [gnome-terminal](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/) for a new terminal window.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in gnome-terminal for a new terminal tab.

Or right click in the terminal and chose `New Terminal` or `New Tab`

The new terminal window or tab inherits the working directory from its parent terminal.

This works also with the [Xfce terminal](http://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/start).

[LXTerminal](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTerminal) only inherits the working directory from its parent terminal on a new tab.

Answer (score 4):

You can make an alias for the current working directory in `~/.bash_aliases`

```
echo alias \'alias-name\'=\"cd "$(pwd)"\" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

Now you can access that directory by running only the alias name on the terminal.

Example:

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~/Desktop/rah$ echo alias \'go\'=\"cd "$(pwd)"\" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

Then i run the below command on a new terminal,

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ go
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~/Desktop/rah$
```

To clear all the aliases,

```
echo "" > ~/.bash_aliases
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open terminal for a current directory and don't want to use cd in terminal to move to current directory then

Install nautilus-open-terminal available in software centre.

you can right click in the current directory and you will find 'open in terminal' option.

You need to restart nautilus after installing to restart nautilus type in terminal

```
nautilus -q (it will quit the nautilus)
```

to start again

```
nautilus
```

Answer (score 1):

[GNOME wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Terminal/FAQ?action=show&redirect=Terminal%252FFAQ#How_can_I_make_new_terminals_start_in_the_working_directory_of_the_current_terminal.3F) suggests sourcing `vte.sh` from your `~/.bashrc` profile.

I.e. add this line to your `~/.barshrc` file:

```
. /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```

This way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>  in gnome-terminal will inherit current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to simplyfy your task ie to save you from typing the CD thing again and again.

#### 1. Make an alias for it to help you go to the directory again and again like

```
vi  ~/.bashrc
```

Add the line mentioned below

```
alias goto='cd ~/path/to/yourdir'
```

Then

```
source  ~/.bashrc
```

Now whenever you want to go to the directory just type goto on your terminal.

it.

## problem : This will require you to make multiple aliases for different directories.

## 2 A function to save your life - extended aliases.

**Steps :**

```
1. vi ~/.bashrc
2. write this 

    function lifesaver(){
    cd "$1"
    }
3. source ~/.bashrc

4. to move to a directory /home/userMusic, use 

    lifesaver /home/userMusic
```

## 3. Installing nautilus-open-terminal .Here's a link to it.

https://askubuntu.com/a/207448/278183

Problem with it is that every time you need to go to the directory manually and then click open terminal.

Choose what suits you the best :-)

Comment: Your 1st solution only works for a specific directory, your second does absolutely nothing. It is the same as using `cd` directly. How is `lifesaver.sh foo/` different from `cd foo/`? The only difference is that it is longer to type. Oh, and you want `cd "$@"`, not `$0`, `$0` is the name of the script so `cd $0` would actually run `cd /usr/bin/lifesaver.sh`.

Comment: Ah, much better, thanks :). I still don't see the point of your 2nd approach though. It is just a more complex way of running the `cd` command. The OP can just do `cd /home/userMusic` why would they use your function?

Comment: i know you are right,but if alias is a right way to change directory then a function would make things generic i guess.

Comment: Not at all, your function just does `cd foo`, if anything, it is _harder_ to use than the simple `cd` and does not offer any extra functionality whatsoever.