# Start terminal at particular directory

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, cd-command

I always need to go at workspace directory using cd, I got bored with this. I want that terminal should be opened at my workspace directory on start, is there any way to do this? Please suggest.

Comment: @hg8 No duplicate (at least not to your linked question). Answer by user "migrc" is correct, as the user wants to change the terminal's default initial working directory.

Comment: My bad I misunderstood...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your `~/.bashrc` and append the `cd` command you want to the end of this file.

```
cd /desired_directory/
```

Now when you open the terminal, the current working directory will be this.

Answer (score 0):

Full answer can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu)

Briefly, what you need is to install nautilus

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

After it, you can right click in any directory and there will be an option called "Open in terminal"