# nautilus-open-terminal in Wily Werewolf 15.10

Tags: nautilus, gnome-terminal, 15.10

I used to use nautilus-open-terminal ( [How to add "Open terminal here" to Nautilus' context menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu) ) a lot, but it seems to be gone in Wily Werewolf 15.10

How do I get it back / what is the most reasonable replacement/workaround?

Comment: That's odd, the feature is still working for me on 15.10, and I didn't have to install anything extra. Do you have nautilus-actions installed as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The official version `nautilus 1:3.14.2-0ubuntu12` from 15.10 (Wily Werewolf)'s official `main` repository already includes the <kbd>Open in terminal</kbd> functionality.

[image]

If you check any folder's context menu, you'll see it's already there without installing any additional package. So `nautilus-open-terminal` is not necessary on 15.10 systems any more.

I can proof this by showing you my list of installed packages containing "nautilus" in their name:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10

$ dpkg -l | grep nautilus
ii  libnautilus-extension1a      1:3.14.2-0ubuntu12     amd64     libraries for nautilus components - runtime version
ii  nautilus                     1:3.14.2-0ubuntu12     amd64     file manager and graphical shell for GNOME
ii  nautilus-data                1:3.14.2-0ubuntu12     all       data files for nautilus
ii  nautilus-sendto              3.8.2-1ubuntu1         amd64     integrates Evolution and Pidgin into the Nautilus file manager
ii  nautilus-share               0.7.3-1ubuntu5         amd64     Nautilus extension to share folder using Samba
```

---

#### Update:

Actually the functionality was already included into Vivid (15.04)'s `nautilus` package, but the `nautilus-open-terminal` package also still existed. Therefore if somebody installed the add-on, he suddenly had the context menu entry <kbd>Open in terminal...</kbd> *twice*!

Comment: It indeed has finally become standard! I had an old customization script that I always use. It failed because the package is gone, but I did not actually check for the functionality. It is there out of the box! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you also need to have `gnome-terminal` installed for this to work. Might be interesting for all users not having installed the full gnome desktop, but e.g. xubuntu and nautilus.

It's not going to fall back on any other terminal you might have installed...