# When I open a terminal from the right click menu on the desktop make my cwd Desktop

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

I personally love being able to use a healthy combination of command line interfaces and graphic interfaces. For instance when navigating through my files I will typically use nautilus, gnome's file browser, or fileZilla on remote systems rather than cd-ing around and reading everything.

That said I love being able to quickly with the right click drop down menu open a terminal at the location that I have browsed to, in fact I have become extremely comfortable with that behavior, so much so that I find it rather jarring when I open a terminal from the right click drop down on my desktop and the terminal opens at my home directory (on above my desktop directory).

I am wondering if there is any way to make it so that when I open a terminal from my desktop it will actually open at the desktop. Obviously I cannot put `cd ~/Desktop` in my .bashrc because that would nuke the behavior that spoiled me in the first place when opening a terminal from the file browser...

Thanks for your input!

Comment: You could try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu

Comment: sorry but this is not it at all, when you click on the desktop (like the one with the colorful background ) the context menu is different from the one  in explorer errr nautilus.