# open in terminal is not working after upgrading to 19.10

Tags: gnome-terminal, 19.10, nautilus-extensions

My terminal always opens in home directory no matter where I open it. I also tried opening another terminal in the different directory but it's not working

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=Downloads
gnome-terminal --working-directory Downloads
gnome-terminal --working-directory /home/avil/Downloads
```

I have also reinstalled both open in terminal extension and gnome-terminal but it's still not working[image]

Comment: https://vitux.com/how-to-open-folders-in-ubuntu/ outlines multiple ways to do that.

Comment: thanks for the reply but that's not what I m asking I know how to change directories I am asking My terminal is not opening in the directory in which iam currently in nautilus. For eg I am in Download folder I choose open in terminal from  context menu terminal will open in home directory

Comment: Try passing full pathname, e.g. `/home/avil/Downloads`. (Note that if you use the shorthand `~/Downloads` then you need to replace the preceding `=` sign with a space because bash doesn't perform tilde-expansion after the equals sign.)

Comment: @egmont it's not working in either way I have ubuntu in my VM and its works! but I don't know why it's not working here.

Comment: do you have `cd ~` or similar in your `.bashrc` ?

Comment: @pLumo I don't have cd ~ in my .bashrc

Comment: I am also in 19.10, but I do not have this problem. Did you try something simple like this: `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/`

Comment: yes it did not worked

Comment: If the directory `/` works, but `/home/avil/Downloads` does NOT, there may be a permission problem. Are you sure that the directory `Downloads` exists? Please paste `ls -dl ~/Downloads` output.

Comment: @FendonKadifeli /also didnt work and Download has permission of rwx-rx-rx so it has permission

Comment: @starkus nautilus . and nautilus .. is working fine for me its opening in correct directory. I will try to debug the terminal thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First launch `terminal` go to `Edit` -> `Profile Preferences` -> `Command` and uncheck the option saying `Run a custom command instead of my shell`. It will not working with Desktop, but if you're browsing the Desktop as a folder inside nautilus, it will works fine.

Comment: hi thanks a lot! Now my open in terminal is working fine thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this problem with Ubuntu 16.04 and only have 19.04 installed on another partition which I haven't upgraded to 19.10 yet to test.

Your problem does sound like this one though:

- [Nautilus open terminal here](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?313877-Nautilus-open-terminal-here)

Please read the entire Q&A but to summarize the answer:

> You need to install gnome-terminal-nautilus or create a custom script.

Then the follow up answer:

> ok, solved, I have change execute command in profile in to
>   gnome-shell. Not very intuitive

Comment: hi thanks for reply but this didn't work for me. 1 Unable to locate package gnome-terminal-nautilus and i have also done the steps but its still not working

Answer (score 1):

- `Open terminal`
- `Go to Preferences`
- To your `profile` of the terminal(if you don't have any, create one)
- In the menu of profile go to `Command`
- Preserve working directory make it `Always`
  This fixed for me. Check the picture for more details.

If you want to open terminal in folder with command keys than :
`shift + F10   E` 
or
 `Right click with mouse` than press  `E`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer [How to add "Open terminal here" to Nautilus' context menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu)

If you have a up to 15.04 Ubuntu distro version you have to install `nautilus-open-terminal` package. In my 19.10 Ubuntu I can't find it, though, because it is already included since version 15.10.

You could also try to reinstall nautilus, after updating your system, if you have a newer distro with `sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus` command.

Answer (score 0):

There's an "Open in Terminal" command in the context menu of any folder in Nautilus. [Right-click on the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW0cF.png) and choose the `Open in Terminal` option (between `Revert to Previous Version...` and `Star`.