# Unable to open terminal in a directory

Tags: nautilus, 20.04, gnome-terminal

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I noticed this issue recently. I cannot open a terminal in a directory by right clicking in the directory and selecting ***"Open in Terminal"***. However, I'm able to launch the terminal from applist and `cd` to any directory. What can be the issue?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add "Open terminal here" to Nautilus' context menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207442/how-to-add-open-terminal-here-to-nautilus-context-menu) For 20.04, see [Asadullah Al Galib's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206655/816190)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I think Nautilus GNOME Terminal extensions are not installed. In recent versions (20.04) that is not installed by default. First quit all Nautilus windows with:

```bsh
nautilus -q
```

Then run:

```bsh
sudo apt install nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
```

Then reboot and open Nautilus.